# Reference request: certain special LFTs

Tags: reference-request, linear-fractional-transformation

$\newcommand{\cs}{\operatorname{cs}}$ My actual question is at the bottom.

Let $$
a\diamond b = \frac{a+b}{1+ab}
$$
and
$$
a\dagger=\dfrac{1-a}{1+a}.
$$
Then
$$
a\dagger\dagger = a
$$
and
\begin{align}
(ab)\dagger & = (a\dagger)\diamond (b\dagger), \\[8pt]
(a\diamond b)\dagger & = (a\dagger)(b\dagger),
\end{align}
and hence
$$
(a\diamond b)\diamond c = a\diamond (b\diamond c)
$$
(and this comes to $\dfrac{a+b+c+abc}{1+ab+ac+bc}$).

If we then let $g(a) = a\diamond a$ and $f(a) = (a\dagger)\diamond (a\dagger)$, then we have
\begin{align}
g(a) & = f(a\dagger) \\[6pt]
f(a) & = g(a\dagger),
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
g\left(\frac 1 a\right) = g(a), & \qquad f\left(\frac 1 a\right) = -f(a), \\[6pt]
g(-a) = -g(a), & \qquad f(-a) = f(a).
\end{align}
Then we have
$$
\tan\frac\alpha2\cdot\tan\frac\beta2= \tan\frac\gamma2 
\iff
\cos\alpha\diamond\cos\beta = \cos\gamma.
$$
Let us define the "stereographic cosine" of $a$ to be the $x$-coordinate of the projection of the point $(0,a)$ onto the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ along a line through the point $(-1,0)$.  Then
$$
\cs a = (a^2)\dagger = (a\dagger)\diamond(a\dagger)
$$
and we have the identity
$$
\cs(a_1\cdots a_n)=\cs a_1 \diamond\cdots\diamond\cs a_n.
$$
(This identity will appear in a forthcoming publication.)

**My question is whether** this somewhat suprisingly complex set of identities, with some of the rhythm of trigonometric identities, following from this seemingly trivially simple set of definitions, has a literature?  Has this seen the light of day somewhere?

Comment: Forgive me if this seems unnecessary. I'm interested in finding out where you get all these very interesting ideas from. What is your motivation?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar : Thank you.  I get them from fiddling with elementary geometry and trigonometry.

Comment: Sir, by forthcoming publication do you mean in a journal? Or preprint like Arxiv?

Comment: This material is somewhat related to the [Gudermannian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function) identities, which connect the circular functions with the hyperbolic functions without (explicit) use of complex numbers.